# Trignometric step calculation

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I was reading how wkb approximation leads to bohr sommerfeld quantization. In the book Sadri Hassani, the authors did the following step:-

[image: Doubt in step]

I couldn't get how this step is done. If you use the equations $cos (x) = cos(-x)$ and $cosA=cosB \implies A=B+2n\pi$, then you get the R.H.S as $(2n+1/2)\pi\hbar$. It may be trivial but I can't understand how the factor of 2 was removed.